# Xcode: ATM Finder App

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary

I want to develop an app that find the nearest ATM, how to I set all this up? Finding you current position and typing the ATM positions.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to go through CLLocationManager class which help you to get your current location

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager   =       [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
 locationManager.delegate         =       self;
 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

following delegate will help you to get the updated location

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

}
```

Now you can use the google place api to search any thing near your current coordinate

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=%.0f&types=%@&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDIWlL",currentlatitude,currentlongitude,distanceinmeters,itemYouWantToSearch];

// here you have to use your own key and change the ivars according to your need.
```

Now you have to use the NSXMLParser to parse the data

```
NSXMLParser *itemParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[itemParser setDelegate:self];
[itemParser parse];
```

following parser delegate will help you to get the data

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

{
 //opening tag
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
  //data of opening tag
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

//closing tag
}
```

Comment: +1 Great comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to read all about XMLParsing, JSON Parsing.
When you will learn all about parsing then go to for next step this is API. Find a URL 
on internet which provides the ATM's detail... I suggest you please before ATM you should use weather API of google... It is easy for beginner.

Comment: if you have satisfied then please up vote :-)